# A variable wrote inside a JSP function is not recognized

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

this function is written inside the HEAD tag of a jsp file and i call it from inside the jsp BODY tag:

```
<%!
public void func1(String var1, String var2)
{
    String Name = var1 + "," + var2;
%>
    <input type='image' name=<%=Name%>
     src='somePath' onclick="submit()"/></br>
<%!
}
%>
```

i'm getting an error message:
"cannot find symbol
symbol: variable Name
location: class SimplifiedJSPServlet"

any suggestion why Name is not recognized ? did i write it properly and placed it in the right place?

Comment: Obligatory reading: [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your variable `Name` is only defined within the first scriplet segment. To declare as a class member variable use:

```
<%!
      String name;
%>
```

outside of any method scoping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<%!
public void func1(String var1, String var2)
{
    String Name = var1 + "," + var2;
    out.println("<input type='image' name='" + Name + "' src='somePath' onclick='submit()'/><br>");
}
%>
```

Then you can call the above method wherever you want in the JSP.

```
Ex: <%= func1("Text1", "Text2") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is only in scope for the duration of the function call.  To access the value you will need to do something like

```
request.setAttribute("name", name);
```

Inside your function (you could use pageContext or request - I don't know what scope you want.

Then outside your function you can simple do

```
<input type='image' name="${name}" />
```